# Link a GtkEditable signal to GtkEntry

Tags: pygtk, gtkentry

I am looking for a way of using the behaviour linked to [`gtk_editable_insert_text`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkEditable.html#GtkEditable-insert-text) in [`GtkEntry`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkEntry.html). The latter does not have a signal emitting this sort of behaviour, and the closest I can get is using [`gtk_entry_activate`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry-activate), however this requires Enter to be pressed once the text has been input. I've been running in circles with this particular signal, and for the sake of usability I would like to have the `insert-text` behaviour instead the one of `activate`.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked a similar question on AskUbuntu and I got an answer from @[Timo](https://askubuntu.com/users/20837/timo). Turns out the problem I was having was caused by a misunderstanding what `gtk_editable_instert_text` actually did. In the end, Timo suggested I use `gtk_focus_out_event` which worked like a charm.